# Access query/SQL - duplicates in one field with distinct multiple 2nd field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on a database with products and lot numbers. Each entry in the Lots table has a Lot Number and a Product description.

Sometimes there are multiple records of the same lot number, for example when an item is repacked a new record is created, but with the same Lot Number and same product description - this is fine. But other times there are problem cases, namely when two **different** products share the same Lot Number. I am trying to find those.

In other words, there are 3 possibilities:

1. Lot numbers for which there is only one record in the table.
2. Lot numbers for which there are multiple records, but the Product description is the same for all of them
3. Lot numbers for which there are multiple records, and the product descriptions are not all the same.

I need to return *only* #3, with a separate record for each instance of that Lot Number and product description.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Thanks Juan for the sample data. Using this example, I want to return the data contained in Id 2-8, but not 1, 9, 10, 11.

Comment: Can you give some sample data and provide the tables schema?

Comment: I add a picture. Hope that is similar to your data ?

Comment: @Emacs The tables are extremely complex, but I have a query to return the relevant data, and would make a second query based on that. Trying to add sample data...

Comment: @Juan where is the picture?

Comment: dont you see a suggest edit in your question?  here is http://i.stack.imgur.com/GHr3E.png you can edit and add a picture. 11 row should say Lot 4, but i guess that is also a possiblity?

Comment: @juan sorry I'm new here :) Now I saw it and added description based on your edit. Thanks

Comment: @Juan and line 11 is good, because demonstrates that one product can have multiple lots

Answer (score 3):

This wasn't easy because lot of time don't use access.

- First select unique values using `distinct`.
- Then count how many diferent product appear on each lotnumber using `group by`
- Last join both result and show only the lots with more than one description `where total >1`

.

```
SELECT id, Product.lotnumber,  Product.Product, total
FROM 
    Product Inner join
    (
    SELECT lotnumber, count(*) as total
    FROM 
        (SELECT distinct lotnumber, product
        FROM Product)
    GROUP BY lotnumber
    ) SubT  On Product.lotnumber = SubT.lotnumber
WHERE total > 1
ORDER BY id
```

As you can see :

- lot 2 have two products (yy and zz)
- lot 3 have thre products (aa, bb, cc)

[image]

I include my product table:

[image]
Sorry for spanish. Field types are Autonumeric, Short Text, and Number

Comment: I tried this but it returned all the lotnumbers that were duplicated, even if the product was the same. Also, when I tried to sort by lot number, I got the error "Invalid operation". This error occurred even if I first ran the query and then used the sort button to sort the result.

Comment: I just include my table in access. Sorry for spanish. Field types are Autonumeric, Short Tex, and Number. You create this table and load the sample data should  have same result

Comment: I update the result picture. This show correct result. Can you duplicate this result with my data table? Otherwise provide your data sample.

Comment: I tried yours and it worked, but with my database it doesn't... It's ODBC  with hundreds of tables, this particular list of Lot numbers has about 115,000 records. The only difference I can see is that I'm using a query for the underlying data instead of a table. But I don't think that should matter...

Comment: First try create a table instead of the query just for discard that. Then try create a small sample data set with the problem to try isolate the issue. Then let me know. But the problem as you describe is already solve and you may consider close this one and make a new question.